# Overlaid rasters has white edges in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

[image]

There are some areas that overlay when I upload this two rasters in ArcMap.
I understand that the white edges can be resolved by ticking the Display Background  Value and put 255 as the value. I tried this method and it works.

But I don't understand why the white edges happened, and why does the 255 value help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is one or both your input or output images an ECW or JPEG? It looks like artifacts from a lossy compression method.

Comment: both are PNG images